# Prevent Treeview selection loss on drag and drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, pygtk, gtktreeview

I have a `gtk.Treeview` setup as a drag source:

```
self.drag_source_set(gtk.gdk.BUTTON1_MASK, targets, gtk.gdk.ACTION_COPY)
```

and it's `TreeSelection` is set to `SELECT_MULTIPLE`.

But everytime I try to drag a multi row selection, the cursor jumps to the current mouse position, resetting the selection to the current row. Even though the mouse is above one of the selected rows. It only works when I hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button down.

What is going on?

**Edit 1:**

I have set up a bare-bones treeview to rule out any bugs in my code and it does the same thing.

**Edit 2:**

I found a code snippet that does what I want. It's from the quod libet sources, called `MultiDragTreeView`.

Comment: Can you give a link for that MultiDragTreeView? Is it in Python?

Comment: Maybe this is that, but source link does not work: http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2006-June/012440.html

Comment: Oh, I found 2 classes: [this](http://www.koders.com/python/fidFF5C3F24E188371DD3A19E2BCF52A6C89BB5CA14.aspx?s=MultiDragTreeView#L26) and [this](http://www.koders.com/python/fidB8058C60799FF28A4C6AB95D011FA5590A7EE46F.aspx?s=MultiDragTreeView#L87)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a code snippet that does what I want. It's from the quod libet sources, called ['MultiDragTreeView'](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/source/browse/quodlibet/quodlibet/qltk/views.py#476). Quoting the docstring:

```python
"""TreeView with multirow drag support:
* Selections don't change until button-release-event...
* Unless they're a Shift/Ctrl modification, then they happen immediately
* Drag icons include 3 rows/2 plus a "and more" count"""
```

Comment: The link no longer works, but I think this is where the code has moved to on GitHub: https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet/blob/release-3.9.1/quodlibet/quodlibet/qltk/views.py#L966

Comment: Quodlibet is GPL licensed, but it looks like the original author of that code has also released it under the MIT license: https://kevinmehall.net/2010/pygtk_multi_select_drag_drop

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this, if item is selected, remove the item from selection and add control mask to the event.:

```
def on_iconview_button_press_event(widget, event):
    if event.type != Gdk.EventType.BUTTON_PRESS or event.button != 1:
        return
    if (event.state & Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK):#do no changes if ctrl is pressed
        return
    path = widget.get_path_at_pos(event.x, event.y)
    if not path:
        return
    if widget.path_is_selected(path):
        widget.unselect_path(path)
        event.state |= Gdk.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK
        return
iconview.connect('button-press-event', on_iconview_button_press_event)
```